# emfield support for itunes?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, itunes

Anyone know how to store the URL or embed code of an iTunes audio-file, in an emaudio field?  Or is there some other way to embed an iTunes file as one field in a Drupal node?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do this in CCK.  Just make a new field and have set the input filter to full HTML. With Embedded Media Filed module you can also set up a filed that will accept a wide range of urls. I don't think I tunes is one of them however it will accept embed tags.

If I'm not understanding you correctly and you are looking to make a podcast feed you can just use the file upload field and upload the file to the node, then use views to create the feed.  I would also suggest running the feed through a service like feedburner for stats and more control.

I think I covered everything...

Comment: The issue is that there is currently no module that works in tandem with emfield to provide iTunes support, analogous for example to media_youtube.module which provides support for youtube emfields. Plus, it does not seem that iTunes provides embed codes for the individual audio files. I am hoping that someone out there has tackled this problem and found a solution.